# Auto-highlight parts of the text which has been changed

Tags: vim, text-editor

Is it possible in VIM to highlight parts of some text the user has added/changed in a file?

Following situation demonstrates this:

1. user has opened a file
2. user has made some changes and then **:w**
3. all differences between 1 and 2 should be highlighted
4. user has made some changes and then **:w**
5. all differences between 1 and 4 should be highlighted

and so on.

I am looking for a most compact solution - should it be an option or a simple vim script.

Comment: Have you considered [gundo](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/gundo.vim/)? It may be sufficient for your needs - this plugin allows you to easily preview diffs between each changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a backup of the original file, then `:vsplit file.bak`， execute `:diffthis` in both buffer.

Comment: This is a nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

The VIM plugin [vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) will indicate lines that have been added / removed / changed if the file you are editing is part of a Git repository.  This might meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Vim tracks and maintains an undo history which records all changes made to a file. You could use a plugin like '[sjl/gundo.vim](https://bitbucket.org/sjl/gundo.vim/src)' which gives you the ability to view diffs of subsequent changes to a file (very handy).

If you keep the file under vcs, like git, you can also see diffs. For git you should use '[tpope/vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)' and then you can view diffs in several different ways, most common being :Gdiff

Answer (score 1):

For such difference reporting, it's best to use a *revision control system*. The numbers from your question then map cleanly to *revision numbers*, and there are indeed plugins that can show those differences (also across multiple revisions, and in the form of log messages, etc.)

The [vcscommand.vim - CVS/SVN/SVK/git/hg/bzr integration plugin](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=90) supports all widely-used systems, and offers this in the form of a *vimdiff* or a unified diff in a scratch buffer. There are also plugins ([vim-signify - Advanced plugin for showing VCS diffs in the SignColumn](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4487), or GitGutter for Git) that visualize this neatly in the *sign column*.

If you don't / can't use a revision control system, there are plugins that show the differences to the *saved version* (but not across saves, as this information is not available).

If you want a lightweight, Vim-only revision control system solution that can do this, have a look at my [writebackup plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1828) and [writebackupVersionControl plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1829) plugins, which offer vimdiffs / unified diffs, too, without requiring an underlying revision control system.